# Haskell monoid foldable rose tree

Tags: class, haskell, monoids

I need to make a foldable instance for a Rose tree data structure:

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

With the following monoid and rose-related class/instances:

```
instance Functor Rose where
    fmap f (a :> bs) = (f a) :> (map (fmap f) bs)

class Monoid a where
    mempty ::           a
    (<>)   :: a -> a -> a

instance Monoid [a] where
    mempty = []
    (<>)   = (++)
```

What I tried:

```
instance Foldable Rose where
    fold (a:>b) =  a <> (foldMap fold b)
```

However this is not working properly, for the system check I get the error:

```
*** Failed! Exception: 'Prelude.undefined': 
[] :> []
```

But I'm not sure why it doesn't work, could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: Instead of updating the solution in your question, why don't you write it here as an answer ?

Comment: Good one, hadn't thought of that possibility!

Comment: how about `deriving (Foldable)` with `{- LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable -}`?

Comment: You may want to check out `Data.Tree` in the `containers` package, which is part of the Haskell Platform and also ships with GHC.

Answer (score 8):

Your implementation of `fold` was correct, there is no reason to change it.

The problem is that `fold` isn't sufficient to define `Foldable`. From [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable):

> `class Foldable t where Source`
>
> Data structures that can be folded.
>
> Minimal complete definition: `foldMap` or `foldr`.

So you must define either `foldMap` or `foldr` (or both). Defining `foldMap` is easier and more natural (and also more effective in many cases). So you should write something like:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Foldable Rose where
    foldMap f (x :> xs) = f x <> foldMap (foldMap f) xs
```

Answer (score 5):

This is only tangentially related, but if you realize that Rose Trees are the same as `Cofree []` from [`Control.Comonad.Cofree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-3.2/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html), then you can get a `Foldable` instance "for free" from the foldable instance of `[]` like so:

```
import Control.Comonad.Cofree
import Data.Foldable as F

type RoseTree = Cofree []
```

Load it up into GHCi:

```
λ> let tree = 1 :< [1 :< [], 2 :< [], 3 :< []] :: RoseTree Int
λ> :t F.foldr (+) 0 tree
F.foldr (+) 0 tree :: Int
λ> F.foldr (+) 0 tree
7
```

You can also just derive `Foldable`, or write your own implementation (like you've done).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like I found the answer to my own question.

Solution:

```
instance Foldable Rose where
    fold (a:>b) =  a <> (foldr (<>) mempty (map fold b))
```

Had to first append each of the elements in the list with the head element (and do the same for each of the bound elements to those rose trees), then fold the list together with an non-adjusting element mempty.

Answer (score 0):

Although OP says he/she has found the answer, the solution lacks the base case:

```
instance Foldable Rose where
    fold (a:>[]) = a <> mempty
    fold (a:>b) =  a <> (foldr (<>) mempty (map fold b))
```

Otherwise an expection about non-exhaustive patterns in function fold will be thrown.